# Acquire FLV URL from YouTube

Tags: c#, regex, youtube, download

There are a lot of questions of a very similar nature, but as of yet I'm unable to find anything which answers this question directly. A lot of responses include "look at the source code of this" and contain a link, unfortunately I'm struggling to analyse the source code in those links, so I'm hoping someone can give me something step by step.

Here is what I have so far:

1. Request link from end user (e.g www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FlgVN03fNM)
2. Send HTTP Request to URL, acquire source.
3. Regex the source to find some information (presumably a series of elements which can be concatenated to form a link to the FLV.
4. Download the FLV.
5. Convert the FLV into MP3 or whichever format you'd like.

I have already achieved steps 1, 2, 5, and they all do exactly what I want, but it seems there is a lack of clarity around how to do step 3. Could someone *please* break this down a little further? Example:

1. Regex for "XXXXXXXXX"
2. This line contains all information you need
3. Split the string by "YYY" to acquire a list of elements
4. Find all the elements which match "ZZZZZ"
5. Use those elements to create the FLV link

This would be very useful to me, and if possible I'd love steps or a very simple application in C# or PHP which extracts the link.

Comment: You need an HTML parser. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Comment: Can this really not be achieved using RegEx? Or better yet, using string manipulation in .NET?

Comment: Can you explicit *some information* ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what could be more clear - in reality it's the detail that I'm lacking, and I guess what I'm looking for is someone who has done this before, or at the very least understands video websites well enough to know how it might be done. I'll add a bit of information soon and some of the C# I've been working on since posting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to skip to a simple code sample for this, you can see the full source on GitHub: https://github.com/XtrmJosh/YouTubeDownloader

I was pretty much right with my assumptions, and although it's taken me 10 hours or so, I've finally achieved what I set out to do. Here is a rough breakdown:

1. Escape string to ensure we don't break anything
2. Run some fancy RegEx and what not to capture the exact areas of string we're looking for
3. Find signatures and what not in each of the URLs we find (we'll find a lot, and we need to narrow them down a fair bit before they can be used)
4. Add the signature we find for each URL to it, otherwise we get trash files
5. Scan for some itags, so we know what file type is associated with each link - I *only* want FLV files.
6. Append the video name to the URL, and download.

So here is the code I'm using to get all the video URLs in a HTML document (YouTube only - so far)

```
    public static List<string> ExtractUrls(string html)
    {
        string title = GetTitle(html);

        List<string> urls = new List<string>();
        string DataBlockStart = "\"url_encoded_fmt_stream_map\":\\s+\"(.+?)&";  // Marks start of Javascript Data Block

        html = Uri.UnescapeDataString(Regex.Match(html, DataBlockStart, RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].ToString());

        string firstPatren = html.Substring(0, html.IndexOf('=') + 1);
        var matchs = Regex.Split(html, firstPatren);
        for (int i = 0; i < matchs.Length; i++)
            matchs[i] = firstPatren + matchs[i];
        foreach (var match in matchs)
        {
            if (!match.Contains("url=")) continue;

            string url = GetTxtBtwn(match, "url=", "\\u0026", 0, false);
            if (url == "") url = GetTxtBtwn(match, "url=", ",url", 0, false);
            if (url == "") url = GetTxtBtwn(match, "url=", "\",", 0, false);

            string sig = GetTxtBtwn(match, "sig=", "\\u0026", 0, false);
            if (sig == "") sig = GetTxtBtwn(match, "sig=", ",sig", 0, false);
            if (sig == "") sig = GetTxtBtwn(match, "sig=", "\",", 0, false);

            while ((url.EndsWith(",")) || (url.EndsWith(".")) || (url.EndsWith("\"")))
                url = url.Remove(url.Length - 1, 1);

            while ((sig.EndsWith(",")) || (sig.EndsWith(".")) || (sig.EndsWith("\"")))
                sig = sig.Remove(sig.Length - 1, 1);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) continue;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sig))
                url += "&signature=" + sig;
            urls.Add(url);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++)
        {
            urls[i] += "&title=";
            urls[i] += title;
        }

        return urls;
    }

    public static string GetTitle(string RssDoc)
    {
        string str14 = GetTxtBtwn(RssDoc, "'VIDEO_TITLE': '", "'", 0, false);
        if (str14 == "") str14 = GetTxtBtwn(RssDoc, "\"title\" content=\"", "\"", 0, false);
        if (str14 == "") str14 = GetTxtBtwn(RssDoc, "&title=", "&", 0, false);
        str14 = str14.Replace(@"\", "").Replace("'", "&#39;").Replace("\"", "&quot;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("+", " ");
        return str14;
    }

    public static string GetTxtBtwn(string input, string start, string end, int startIndex, bool UseLastIndexOf)
    {
        int index1 = UseLastIndexOf ? input.LastIndexOf(start, startIndex) :
                                      input.IndexOf(start, startIndex);
        if (index1 == -1) return "";
        index1 += start.Length;
        int index2 = input.IndexOf(end, index1);
        if (index2 == -1) return input.Substring(index1);
        return input.Substring(index1, index2 - index1);
    }
```

This code will (with the current YouTube format) provide a link to an FLV file which you can download and do what you like with (within the TOS of YouTube). I then used this to find the highest quality link from those that this code provided:

```
    public static string GetFLV(List<string> urls)
    {
        // Acquire a list of links which match the criteria for being FLV files
        List<string> flvurls = new List<string>();
        foreach (string url in urls)
        {
            string itag = Regex.Match(url, @"itag=([1-9]?[0-9]?[0-9])", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].ToString();
            int itagint;
            int.TryParse(itag, out itagint);

            if (itagint == 5 || itagint == 6 || itagint == 34 || itagint == 35)
            {
                flvurls.Add(url);
            }
        }

        // If we didn't find any FLVs, we return a fatal error and cause a bug later on
        if (flvurls.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fatal error | iTag could not be found for FLV filetype. Please contact software vendor for assistance.");
            return "";
        }
        // If we did find some FLVs, we need to find the highest quality FLV
        else
        {
            #region findBestFLV
            foreach (string url in flvurls)
            {
                string itag = Regex.Match(url, @"itag=([1-9]?[0-9]?[0-9])", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].ToString();
                int itagint;
                int.TryParse(itag, out itagint);
                if (itagint == 35)
                {
                    return url;
                }
            }
            foreach (string url in flvurls)
            {
                string itag = Regex.Match(url, @"itag=([1-9]?[0-9]?[0-9])", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].ToString();
                int itagint;
                int.TryParse(itag, out itagint);
                if (itagint == 34)
                {
                    return url;
                }
            }
            foreach (string url in flvurls)
            {
                string itag = Regex.Match(url, @"itag=([1-9]?[0-9]?[0-9])", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].ToString();
                int itagint;
                int.TryParse(itag, out itagint);
                if (itagint == 6)
                {
                    return url;
                }
            }
            foreach (string url in flvurls)
            {
                string itag = Regex.Match(url, @"itag=([1-9]?[0-9]?[0-9])", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].ToString();
                int itagint;
                int.TryParse(itag, out itagint);
                if (itagint == 5)
                {
                    return url;
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Fatal error | Something has gone horrible wrong whilst finding the best FLV to use. Run, brave warrior, for the end is near.");
        return "";
    }
```

Note it is very scrappy at the minute, the rest of the code is mostly snippets I've borrowed and edited slightly, but this bit I've written from my head in some rushed attempt to get something together for SOF.

Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more concise implementation based on [Pafy](http://np1.github.io/pafy/):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using HttpUtility = System.Web.HttpUtility;
using NameValueCollection = System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection;
using WebClient = System.Net.WebClient;

class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        string videoID = "2FlgVN03fNM";
        string[] itagByPriority = {"5", "6", "34", "35"};

        string videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US&video_id=" + videoID;
        string encodedVideo = null;

        using (var client = new WebClient()) {
            encodedVideo = client.DownloadString(videoUrl);
        }

        NameValueCollection video = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(encodedVideo);

        string encodedStreamsCommaDelimited = video["url_encoded_fmt_stream_map"];
        string[] encodedStreams = encodedStreamsCommaDelimited.Split(new char[]{','});
        var streams = encodedStreams.Select(s => HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s));

        var streamsByPriority = streams.OrderBy(s => Array.IndexOf(itagByPriority, s["itag"]));
        NameValueCollection preferredStream = streamsByPriority.LastOrDefault();

        if (preferredStream != null) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}&signature={1}", preferredStream["url"], preferredStream["sig"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is indeed considerably more tidy than mine, but I feel it is somewhat more difficult to understand at the same time, due to extensive method nesting (I think that's the term - preferredStream = ~~~ is a bit long for my liking. I'll upvote regardless but will take my own answer unless something else crops up. Thanks!

Comment: That's usually called "method chaining." I like that style, but I agree that it can be hard to understand due to the lack of variable names. I've converted it to a more traditional style which might be easier to understand.